# Render html partial in JSON JBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder

I am rendering JSON of some students using JBuilder in Rails 4. I want each student to have a "html" attribute that contains the HTML partial for a given student:

```
[
  { html: "<b>I was rendered from a partial</b>" }
]
```

I have tried the following:

```
json.array! @students do |student|
  json.html render partial: 'students/_student', locals: { student: student }
end
```

But this gives me:

```
Missing partial students/_student with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :haml]}.
```

Comment: try `render partial: '/students/student'`

Comment: That doesn't work either

Comment: what's the name of your partial? where does it live?

Comment: render partial: '/students/student' may not have worked because of that leading /.  Try: render partial: 'students/student'

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to specify the partial format as Rails will look for partial with current format (json) by default. For example:

```
render partial: 'students/student.html.erb'
```

Comment: I tried `render partial: 'students/student.html.haml'` but got `Missing partial students/stundent.html.haml with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :haml]}.`

Comment: stundent? seems like a typo. If you copied from my answer, I had the same typo there.

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify the partial format:

```rb
json.array! @students do |student|
  json.html render(student, formats: [:html])
end
```

Comment: json.array! @students do |student|
  json.html render('student', formats: [:html])
end

Comment: thanks, it work fine. 
````
json.array! @students do |student|
  json.html render(student, formats: [:html])
end
````

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

```rb
# students/index.json.jbuilder
json.array! @students do |student|
  json.html render partial: 'student.html.erb', locals: { student: student }
end

# students/_student.html.erb
<h4><%= student.name %></h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails partials use an underscore in the filename but not in the code when referenced as a string (depending on how you are loading them of course).  Usually a partial called posts/_post.html.haml  will be referenced in code as render :partial => 'posts/post'

Comment: the path the partial points to usually refers to a relative path from the app/views folder.